# How to convert my href links to laravel

Tags: laravel-4

```
<li><a href="./asia//southkorea//bulgoli.php" target = container> Bulgoli </a></li>
```

Hello guys! how can i convert this link to laravel?

Answer (score 2):

use the HTML::link() method

```
{{ HTML::link("./asia//southkorea//bulgoli.php") }}
```

Comment: <li><a href= {{ HTML::link("./asia//southkorea//bulgoli.php") }} target = container> Bulgoli </a></li> like this?

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /smd/public/{{ HTML::link('./asia//southkorea//bulgoli.blade.php') }} on this server.
Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.0.23 Server at localhost Port 80